# How do you set an initial zoom of a bokeh plot?

Tags: bokeh

I have a plot that uses values from the some original data (within an x/y range of 0-20), and some minimization data that results in some fairly large x/y values (e.g. -1000 to 1000+). Because of this, the plots I'm doing require me to manually click zoom to see the relevant portion of just the source data.

Is there a way in bokeh (python/js plotting library) to set the initial zoom? I noticed there's a box-zoom button, but that's still a manual step of clicking and zooming in the area every time.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the solution is to use the x_range and y_range arguments in the figure command, e.g.

```
plot = figure(width=1000, height=1000, x_range=(7, 10), y_range=(-5, 25) )
```

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#setting-ranges